# Coercing type abbreviated records

Tags: ocaml, record, coercion

Why can't I coerce record types in OCaml? Base types like `int` works fine.

Below is an example where I construct a base module `M` which I include in module `A`. `M.t` is type abbriviated in `A`. As long as `M.t` is `int`, I can do `A.t' :> M.t`. When I change it to `{i : int}`, the compiler says it's not a subtype. I'm guessing there is a very specific reason for this?

```
module M = struct
  type t = {i : int}
  let make () = {i = 10}
end

module A : sig
  include module type of M
  type t' = private t
  val make : unit -> t'
end = struct
  include M
  type t' = t
end
```

In the toplevel:

```
(A.make() :> M.t);;
Error: Type A.t' is not a subtype of M.t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `A.t'` has no relation to `M.t`, because `include` does not "preserve" equality, it just literally duplicates the module structure (or signature) and inlines it in place (as fresh types and values). So type `M.t` doesn't have any relation to `A.t` and therefore to `A.t'` (and different record types do not have structural subtyping defined like say objects or modules).
Obvious fix is `type t' = private M.t`.

**UPDATE**

It appears the above is not fully correct, because `type t' = private M.t` in signature and `include M type t' = t` in implemention do typecheck, so `include M` preserves the equality (otherwise it couldn't match the signature `type t' = private M.t`), unlike copypasting the contents of `M` in the place of `include M`. But this "obviously" doesn't hold for `include module type of` which creates fresh types..

Comment: Another fix is to explicitly state that you want the types to be equal when you include the module type: `include module type of M with type t = M.t`.

Comment: Do you know why this is necessary for record types but not for basic types like `int`? If you change t to `type t = int`, the above code will work.

Comment: Because in `type t = int` and `type t' = int` - `t` and `t'` are aliases (type abbreviation) for existing type and can be used interchangeably. But `type t = {x : int}` and `type t' = {x:int}` - those are two new types and not related at all.